# can a tkinter canvas be filled with a mix of random ones and zeroes? (Python)

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I am in process of creating John Conway's Game of Life and was wondering (because I'm fairly new to python) if there is any way I can fill a tkinter canvas with one's and zeroes to have them represent the alive and dead cells.

As I have started a program but I haven't done it the way I am asking in this question. The way I have done it is I am storing a dictionary holding the rectangles name and coordinates as the key value pair.

So if you have any solutions on how to implement in such a way I'd like to hear them.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: yes, you can do that. Is that all you want to know? Why not just try to do it and see what happens?

Comment: I'd also like to know how and how it could be implemented. @BryanOakley

Answer (score 1):

In the following example, I'm assuming the keys to a dictionary are a tuple of the row and column, and the value is either a 1 or 0. I'm setting the size of a cell to be 10x10 pixels. The example also defines a tag that looks like "*row*,*column*" (eg: "3,4") so that you can easily set the color of a specific cell.

```
size=10  # pixels per cell
for row, column in data.keys():
    tag = f"{row},{column}"
    x0 = column*size
    y0 = row*size
    x1 = x0+size
    y1 = y0+size
    color = "red" if data[(row,column)] == 1 else "white"
    canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=color, tags=(tag,))
```

Using the tag, you can configure a specific cell via its row and column like this:

```
canvas.itemconfigure("4,5", fill="yellow")
```

A simple way to initialize the dictionary would be with this basic loop:

```
data = {}
for row in range(20):
    for column in range(20):
        data[(row, column)] = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer is it possible for you to show me how to set up your dictionary keys in such a way please?